# how to show chars on default page?

Tags: html, angularjs

I page web aplication with `index.html`  file where is my login page. after succes log in I want to load page with **`routeProvider`** where i am using charts to draw diagrams . I have Error when i am loading just index.html for logg in  not even this page where i am using charts.

my error looks like

```
Error: Please set height and width for the chart element
i@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular-charts.min.js:1:12049
Y/<@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:70:91
Z@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:70:149
A@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:59:203
g@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:51:299
g@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:51:316
g@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:51:316
g@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:51:316
F/<@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:50:415
ngViewFillContentFactory/<.link@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular-route.js:983:7
Z@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:70:149
A@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:59:203
g@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:51:299
F/<@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:50:415
I/<@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:52:283
l@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:56:293
update@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular-route.js:933:25
Pe/this.$get</l.prototype.$broadcast@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:128:120
commitRoute/<@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular-route.js:616:15
f/<@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:112:20
Pe/this.$get</l.prototype.$eval@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:125:301
Pe/this.$get</l.prototype.$digest@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:122:390
Pe/this.$get</l.prototype.$apply@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:126:56
l@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:81:169
S@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:85:301
vf/</D.onload@http://localhost:8080/pos/js/angular.min.js:86:315
 <div data-ac-chart="'pie'" data-ac-data="cityData" data-ac-config="cityConf" class="chart ng-isolate-scope" id="chart">
```

here is my `html` file where i have charts

```
<div class="row-fluid maginTopDiv">

    <div class="span4">
        <h2>City</h2>

        <div 
            data-ac-chart="'pie'" 
            data-ac-data="cityData" 
            data-ac-config="cityConf" 
            class="chart" id="chart">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
        <h2>Type</h2>

        <div 
            data-ac-chart="'pie'" 
            data-ac-data="termTypeData" 
            data-ac-config="termTypeConf" 
            class="chart" id="chart">
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="span4">
        <h2>Program ID</h2>

        <div 
            data-ac-chart="'pie'" 
            data-ac-data="programIdData" 
            data-ac-config="programIdConf" 
            class="chart" id="chart">
        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

here is my css content for this divs

```
.chart{
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
}
```

my config for routing

```
app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider


    .when('/', {
            templateUrl: 'home.htm',
            controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/dashboard', {
            templateUrl: 'home.htm',
            controller: 'mainController'
    })
    .when('/archive',{
            templateUrl: 'problemArchive.htm',
            controller: 'mainController'

    })
    .otherwise({
            templateUrl: 'home.htm',
            controller: 'mainController'
    });
});
```

and in controller i am defining data for this charts after successuly logg in and after login i am getting data on the page except this charts.

why i have this errors when i even not loading this page i just have index.html page where i am not using charts, just after log in

Comment: Do what the error says. Set `height` and `width` for the chart element/directive. They must be set via the HTML since it's a directive, CSS won't help you here.

Comment: I tried to set them in js controller  document.getElementById("chart").style.width='100%';
      document.getElementById("chart").style.height='200px'; but it did not help me , same error

Comment: No, set them in your HTML. The same way you set `data-ac-chart` attribute.

Comment: how can i do it ?

Comment: Try something like `data-width="..."` or `width="..."`, and the same for height.